# Blob corrupt data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am french, sorry for my poor english...

I am trying to send 2 files to a PHP script (json data and a JPG pictures). The PHP script creates an archive ".tar.gz" or simply .tar with this two files and others on server side, then send the archive to the client.

On client side, when i try to save archive file (with FileSaver lib) the archive is corrupted. I tried to monitor HTTP response with wireshark and extract the archive, and the file is correct. So the problem is in Javscript script:

HTML part:

```
<div class="col-sm-1" >
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="button_distrib" onclick="toggle_distribe()">Distribuer</button>
        <div id="input_open_image" class="hidden">
            <form method="post" id="fileinfoimage"  onsubmit="return submitFormImage();">
                <p class="btn btn-default">Photo de présentation:<input type="file" name="uploadFileImage" class="btn btn-default"/></p>
                <input type="submit" value="Télécharger" name="submit" class="btn btn-default"/>
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
```

PHP script:

```
<?php
$file = '/tmp/cv.tar';
$json = '/tmp/json';

try {
    $a = new PharData($file);
        file_put_contents ($json, $_POST['json']);
    $a->addFile('cv.html', 'cv/cv.html');
    $a->addFile('js/cv.js', 'cv/js/cv.js');
    $a->addFile('js/cv.js', 'cv/js/cv.js');

    $a->addFile('js/bootstrap.min.js', 'cv/js/bootstrap.min.js');
    $a->addFile('js/jquery.min.js', 'cv/js/jquery.min.js');
    $a->addFile('js/trianglify.min.js', 'cv/js/trianglify.min.js');
    $a->addFile('js/background.js', 'cv/js/background.js');

    $a->addFile('css/bootstrap.min.css', 'cv/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    $a->addFile('css/cv.css', 'cv/css/cv.css');

    $a->addFile($json, 'cv/data/cv.json');

    $a->addFile($_FILES['uploadFileImage']['tmp_name'], 'cv/icons/photo.jpg');


} catch (Exception $e) {
}

$filegz= $file. ".gz";
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/x-tgz');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();

    ob_get_clean();
    echo gzcompress(readfile($file));
    ob_end_flush();

    unlink($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Javascript part:

```
function submitFormImage() 
{
        console.log("submit event image");
        var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById("fileinfoimage"));
        fd.append("json", JSON.stringify(generate()));
        $.ajax({
            url: "archive.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: fd,
            processData: false, 
            contentType: false, 
            async: false
        }).done(function( data ) {
                alert(data.length);
                var bytes = new Uint8Array(data.length);
                for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
                        bytes[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
                var blob = new Blob([bytes], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
                alert(blob.size);
                saveAs(blob, "cv.tar");
        });
        return false;
}
```

Have you any idea for a solution.

Thanks